# elegant way to filter out non numeric input

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, logic

```
if (input >= 0 && input <= 100 ) {}
```

*The variable input is directly filled with the content of an inputfield. I do not only wish to only get input in the specific arange but als only numbers. How can i extend the condition on top that it only accepts numbers as input and not for example the input a?*

Comment: Hi. Why not use a number input in your HTML to begin with... `<input type="number" min="0" max="100">`

Comment: *"...and not for example the input a?"*: already with your current code, "a" will not enter the `if` block.

Comment: "JavaScript validate that variable is a number" seems like that would return results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure it's a number first, with something like

```
const parsedInput = parseInt(input);
if (!isNaN(parsedInput) && parsedInput >= 0 && parsedInput <= 100) { }
```

Once you parsed the input, you can verify if is `not isNaN` where [NaN stands for "Not a Number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

You need to parse it first because isNaN tries to convert the number, so that `isNaN('10')` returns `true`. If you parse it first with `parseInt`, you're good to go :)

Otherwise without parsing it you might have a string in that variable. Javascript is dummy and still evaluates `'10' >= 0` as true, but if you can enforce to have a number is better.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was one more bracket. Give it a try now :)

Comment: `You need to parse it first because isNaN tries to convert the number` what would `parseInt` do in case of `'10'`?

Comment: It would return 10 :)
I'll expand in the answer what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Often `parseInt` is suggested to interpret a string as number, but it has two downsides:

- It *parses*... meaning it stops parsing as soon as it finds a bad character and then returns the result so far achieved. Like `parseInt("55ab") == 55`
- It returns integers, so for input that has a fractional part you'll not get that fraction. In that case `parseFloat` could be suggested, but that also has the behaviour mentioned in the first point.

You can overcome those aspects using either the `Number` function or the unary `+`. The latter really is the shortest and fastest:

```
let num = +input;
if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
    // processing logic comes here
}
```

Note that all these solutions will recognise strings using scientific notation (using `e`) or the `0x` or `0b` prefix for hexadecimal or binary notation.